# Crash in boost::coroutine library when used alongside boost::property_tree XML parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-propertytree, boost-coroutine

I'm using [Simple-Web-Server](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server) library for creating simple web service for translation of **XML** to **JSON** and vice versa. On its turn it uses several **boost** libraries as well **boost::coroutine** among them. For **XML<->JSON** conversion I'm using **boost::property_tree** library for intermediate representation. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <server_http.hpp>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::property_tree;

using HttpServer = SimpleWeb::Server<SimpleWeb::HTTP>;

int main()
{
  HttpServer server(8080, 1);

  server.resource["^/json_to_xml$"]["POST"] = [](auto& response, auto request) {
    try
    {
      ptree pt;
      read_json(request->content, pt);
      ostringstream json, xml;
      write_json(json, pt);
      clog << "JSON request content:" << endl << json.str() << endl;
      write_xml(xml, pt, xml_writer_make_settings<ptree::key_type>(' ', 1u));
      clog << "XML response content:" << endl << xml.str() << endl;
      response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << xml.str().length() << "\r\n\r\n" << xml.str();
    }
    catch(const exception& e)
    {
      cerr << "Error:" << endl << e.what() << endl;
      response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: " << strlen(e.what()) << "\r\n\r\n" << e.what();
    }
  };

  server.resource["^/xml_to_json$"]["POST"] = [](auto& response, auto request) {
    try
    {
      ptree pt;
      read_xml(request->content, pt, xml_parser::trim_whitespace | xml_parser::no_comments);
      ostringstream xml, json;
      write_xml(xml, pt, xml_writer_make_settings<ptree::key_type>(' ', 1u));
      clog << "XML request content:" << endl << xml.str() << endl;
      write_json(json, pt);
      clog << "JSON response content: " << endl << json.str() << endl;
      response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << json.str().length() << "\r\n\r\n" << json.str();
    }
    catch(const exception& e)
    {
      cerr << "Error:" << endl << e.what() << endl;
      response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: " << strlen(e.what()) << "\r\n\r\n" << e.what();
    }
  };

  server.start();

  return 0;
}
```

**JSON** to **XML** conversion works fine but the opposite causes the program to crash. When I'm not using **boost::property_tree**'s **XML** parser in the server's callback the program works fine. [Here](http://pastebin.com/gh7hifRH) is the result of execution. [Here](http://pastebin.com/i7hSKkMa) is **GDB** backtrace. And finally [here](https://justpaste.it/uxq6) is **Valgrind** output.

Used version of the **boost** libraries is *1.58.0* but the same result is observed with the newest version *1.61.0*. Version *1.4.2* of the **Simple-Web-Server** is used.

Comment: That's a lot of code. It would appear as if the Simple-Web-Server isn't production ready code. I've looked at it for a while but there are so many moving parts it's hard to get a handle on things.

Comment: The web service no longer crashes with [version 2.0](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server/tree/v2.0) of *Simple-Web-Server* which doesn't uses *boost::coroutine* any more, but I wondering whether this is some kind of incompatibility between *boost::coroutine* and *boost::property_tree* because I used both in the past and I have similar strange crashes described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610415/what-causes-a-random-crash-in-boostcoroutine) question. Back then I didn't relate it to *boost::property_tree* XML parsing, but now I think that there can be some connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read_xml() might be overflowing your coroutine's stack; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030285/boostproperty-treeread-xml-segfaults-in-an-asio-handler-spawned-using-boost) about a similar crash traced down to a 64K stack variable inside the rapidxml parser.

EDIT. To summarize the link... the gist of the matter is, the rapidxml parser buried within read_xml allocates 64K on the stack, which overflows the 8K default coroutine stack on Linux. You can try two things... either force that stack variable to be smaller, e.g.,

```
#define BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_RAPIDXML_STATIC_POOL_SIZE 512
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
```

or allocate a larger stack when the coroutine is spawned (if it's possible to access that through Simple-Web-Server)

Comment: Great answer! I'm waiting for this so long. We had a similar problem with production code in my previous company which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610415/what-causes-a-random-crash-in-boostcoroutine) and back than we didn't recognize that the problem is in RapidXML.